# Laravel 7.14 loading social links with for each loop on header

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a datatable for social links. a user can edit the link whenever he wants.

Just link any other crud it is very simple. I am trying to load all the links in blade view with icons in header of my app. I created as function and added a for each loop in the snippets.

here's my controller:

```
public function socials()
{
    $socials = Social::all();

    return view('inc.subheader')->with('socials', $socials);
}
```

Here's blade snippent:

```
<div class="col-md-3 justify-content-center social-links">
        <ul class="nav d-flex justify-content-center">
            @foreach ($socials as $social)
            <li class="">
                <a href="{{ $social->link }}" class="btn"><i class="{{ $social->icon }} fa-2x"></i></a>
            </li>   
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The error I'm getting is "$socials is undefined" and when I go on localhost/inc/social I only see three dots and no  icons with links.

Comment: you can clear view, cache, and also composer dump-autoload, and let's see that happen.

Comment: Did not work. Still same error.

Comment: try to dd the variable and let's see what haapen ?

Comment: On dd I'm getting all the values from datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
return view('inc.subheader')->with('socials', $socials);
```

to this:

```
return view('inc.subheader', compact('socials'));
```

Comment: `->with('socials', $socials)` and `view('inc.subheader', compact('socials'))` do exactly the same thing in this case. How is this supposed to help?

Comment: Though it's the same thing but I still tried. And it's not working.

Comment: `with` puts data in `session`

Answer (score 0):

You can try all combination :

```
return view('inc.subheader', compact('socials'));
return view('inc.subheader', [ 'socials'=> $socials]);
```